# How to fill kernel entropy without X and hardware RNG?

Tags: random, linux-kernel, kernel, random-seed, entropy

I have a tiny embedded device running Linux but with no hardware RNG driver and without X server (no mouse, no keyboard...).

```
/dev/random
```

blocks very quickly.

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
```

reports very low numbers (~10).

The system handles a camera so there is a real source of entropy. How can I input entropy into the kernel?

Comment: I suspect this question would be a much better fit on [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: I'm more interested by code than a command line. I would like to understand where in the kernel the entropy is put in. There is the haveged project (incorporated in very recent kernel) but my kernel is old.

Comment: Write and read /dev/urandom.  It uses the same entropy sources but doesn't block.  Writing random data to it adds entropy to the pool but it isn't counted by /dev/random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a data stream from your camera, hash it using something decent like BLAKE2b or SHA2, then feed it into `/dev/random`.

Once the entropy count is `>=256` you are good to go.

From then only read from `/dev/urandom/`.

`/dev/urandom` will happily spew out cryptographically secure pseudorandom data suitable for key material once the system has `256` bits of entropy available.

Running out of entropy after you've collected this amount is a myth. Use `/dev/urandom`, really, it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a try with `haveged`.

It comes with most distributions, you can also install it easily on custom distributions.

It's a userspace daemon that is meant to solve your problem.
cf. man page here: https://linux.die.net/man/8/haveged